# Optional key/value in method call

Tags: ruby, methods, parameter-passing

*This question strictly is about **elegantly** calling a method with variable amounts of "hashified" arguments.*

## Background

I have this method:

```
def meth(a, b, c={})
...
end
```

I usually call it like this:

```
meth(123, 456, arg1: 234, arg2: 543)
```

The method definition should not be changed in any way, form or fashion.

## Problem

Now I wish to skip the `args: 543` if a certain condition is false.

Pseudocode, not valid Ruby:

```
meth(123, 456, arg1: 234, cond ? (arg2: 543) : () )
```

Is there a very elegant, short and easy to understand syntax for this *without changing or monkeypatching the method definition*?

## What I tried

The obvious solution would be something like...

```
args = { arg1: 234 }
args[:arg2] = 543 if cond
meth(123, 456, args)
```

Too ugly.

```
meth(123, 456, {arg1: 234}.merge(cond ? {arg2: 543} : {}))
```

That's ok'ish, but... well... not 100% readable at a first glace when the actual code gets slightly longer.

I tried playing around with the `*` and `**` operator but did not find a solution that looked any better.

Comment: "Too ugly." - it is the way to go.

Comment: `meth(123, 456, arg1: 234, arg2: (543 if cond))` is a valid ruby, but I think your last try is better.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko et al: I appreciate the sentiment. This question is not about general programming paradigms, but a very specific, and I believe very clear issue. I am aware of "Kathinka's Law", but it's really not necessary to convince me of the invalidity of the question, concerning its priority. You never know what good idea might crop up!

Comment: @Ilya, it's valid ruby but does not fit the question. For whatever crooked reason, I absoltely need `:arg2` not to be in the hash (not even with a `nil` value as your offer would produce). Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go with an `ugly` solution. You should prioritise simplicity and readability over code smartness.

To answer your original question, you could do something like this:

```
args = { arg1: 234, arg2: (543 if cond) }
meth(123, 456, args)
```

Comment: My answer *is* about simplicity and readibility. I am asking whether there is a simple and readable solution for what I am wanting to do. I am pretty deep into Ruby and cannot think of anything; treat this question like a "last call for help". ;) The solution you gave does not do what I need btw, it ends up with `arg2: nil`. I need the key `arg2` to not occur in the parameter hash.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the third argument a method call that executes the necessary conditional.

```
meth(123, 457, check_cond(234, 543, object-that-contains-conditionals-data));
```

This is much clearer, and is prettier than other choices.